# Android WebView: Exceptions are not caught

Tags: exception, webview, android-webview

I followed the approach of defining a Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler in the onCreate Method of my application. This application is also defined as such in the manifest. The handler is also created but its handler is never called although I do see a JavaScript error in the LogCat.

```
12-19 03:02:58.630: I/chromium(1569): [INFO:CONSOLE(45)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: $contactArea is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/DefaultPage.html (45)
```

The handler is defined in my app:

```
public class HPAWebView extends Application {

private static Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, final Throwable ex) {
            // Custom code here to handle the error.
            Toast.makeText(HPAWebView.getAppContext(), "Oh no! " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    HPAWebView.context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return HPAWebView.context;
}

}
```

...and this application is stated in the manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="sap.com.prototype.webview.HPAWebView"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom exception handler is not able to catch JavaScript exceptions. You could register a JavaScript interface in your WebView and then call it in response to the JavaScript error event. Let me know if this makes sense or I can clarify more.